# how to fetch the table date using outer join query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have three table,table names are `user`,`trade`,`trade_photo`.Here I have attached the table.

my problem is,

I want to select the trade table_table image data.

how to select the image based in user_id?
[image]
please any one help to me?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the data rather than an image.

Comment: Also, please show the structure for the other 2 tables

Comment: this image needs magnifying glass to read so please post the proper table structure

Comment: user table have a user_id.trade table have user_id and trade_id.trade_photo have a image column this is stored based on the trade_id.

Comment: my problem is: i must select the image column data based in user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
select * from user u,trade t, trade_photo tp where u.user_id=t.user_id and t.trade_id=tp.trade_id;
```

if you want to select for a particular user

```
select * from user u,trade t, trade_photo tp where u.user_id=some_id and u.user_id=t.user_id and t.trade_id=tp.trade_id;
```

Comment: it work correctly buy how to i remove duplicate data?.i use DISTINCT but it not work.this is my query:select DISTINCT * from  trade t, trade_photo tp where 2!=t.user_id

Comment: distinct will give you the unique row result in the resultset. do you want only one row to be returned ?

Answer (score 0):

Whith the supplied information

**user**

- user_id

**trade**

- user_id
- trade_id

**trade_photo**

- image
- trade_id

You can try something as

```
select 
u.user_id ,
t.image
from 
trade_photo tp
inner join trade t on t.trade_id = tp.trade_id
inner join user u on u.user_id = t.user_id 
where u.user_id  = '{some user id}'
```

> Its always better to provide some sample data and expected output, so
>   that a proper suggestion could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to join user table since user_id is already in the trade table.

Comment: if the user_id does not exist in the user table then what happens ?